ACPI Error on booting Ubuntu on Thinkpad
I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen  with Ryzen 5 processor and RENOIR graphics card.
Whenever I boot my laptop I get the following error messages. Please let me know how to resolve them. I have been getting these errors for a few months now.
Sometimes the WiFi also stops working and one gets a longer error message. I will post that when I click a picture of that.


These are not errors they are messages there is noting that needs to be fixed. Many machines will show theses messages or some thing like these. I have 6 machines all show these or something like these. It does not effect the machine or the OS function.
Only if the machine fails to boot is there anything that needs to be fixed.

I see, recently my laptop is also facing charging issues. It does not charge immediately when connected to the power, so I was worried whether this ACPI error has anything to do with it.

Separate issue you may want to make a question regarding that. If you like the answer please accept it.

I see you have accepted the answer but did not upvote it. Could you please do that.
